# Uvicorn would not stop reloading

Tags: python, uvicorn

`ui.run(title='Chat with Autogen Assistant',host='localhost',uvicorn_reload_excludes='.groupchat/**/*')`

Have this app which keeps reloading on changes in files in this directory. I have tried

`uvicorn_reload_excludes='.*,'`

`uvicorn_reload_excludes='**/*'`

`reload=False`

The [docs](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#reloading-without-watchfiles) say

> --reload-exclude  - Specify a glob pattern to match files or directories which will excluded from watching. May be used
> multiple times. By default the following patterns are excluded: .*,
> .py[cod], .sw.*, ~*. These defaults can be overwritten by including
> them in --reload-include.

What to use to exclude everything? or even just .py files everywhere?